# How to Integrate libxml2 native lib in Android-NDK project using CMakeLists.txt and AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, libxml2

Please assist me for using `libxml2` native-lib - **XML** parsing library in **Android NDK** using `CMakeLists.txt` configuration.

I found a source [here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_libxml2). But do not know how to integrate this using `CMakeLists.txt` in **AndroidStudio**. And what need to include from this repository in my android-NDK project to use libxml2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some search and effort i found some solution. So i would like to answer my own question in following steps :

1. Clone the source from [android/platform_external_libxml2](https://github.com/android/platform_external_libxml2) in your machine.

2.Add the required all source as well as header files at appropriate place in your project.

3.With the help of Android.bp file, i managed to configure my app/CMakeList.txt

4.Configure your app or library level build.gradle file.

Here is My CMakeLists.txt :

```
                cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

                set(LIBXML2_SOURCES

                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/SAX.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/entities.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/encoding.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/error.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/parserInternals.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/parser.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/tree.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/hash.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/list.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlIO.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlmemory.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/uri.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/valid.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xlink.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/debugXML.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xpath.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xpointer.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xinclude.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/DOCBparser.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/catalog.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/globals.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/threads.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/c14n.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlstring.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/buf.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlregexp.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlschemas.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlschemastypes.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlunicode.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlreader.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/relaxng.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/dict.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/SAX2.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlwriter.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/legacy.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/chvalid.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/pattern.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlsave.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/xmlmodule.c
                src/main/cpp/libxml2/src/schematron.c
        )

        include_directories(src/main/cpp/libxml2/include)

        include_directories(src/main/cpp/libxml2/src)

        add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         myexampe-native

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/cpp/my-native.cpp )

         add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         mylibxml2

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         ${LIBXML2_SOURCES} )

         target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.

                   myexampe-native

                   mylibxml2
                   )
```

And Here is my app/build.gradle configuration

```
              android { .....
              defaultConfig { .....

              externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=gnu++11"
            arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21',
                      '-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared','-DANDROID_ARM_MODE=arm'

        }
    }
```

Comments are welcomed for any clarification.
Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did you add icu library? I'm getting "unicode/ucnv.h file not found" error, after applying your solution. icu library includes ucnv.h file.

Comment: Also, I have encountered "error: use of undeclared identifier 'xmlOnceInit'". Its reason is that LIBXML_THREAD_ENABLED is not defined. So, I have defined it manually and problem is solved. However, this is not proper way. Actually before compilation it should be configured by '--with-threads', but I couldn't configure it correctly. In Android.bp, libicuuc is added for shared_libs. So, I'm trying to add libicuuc to my project.

Comment: @OğuzhanKoşar
iconv is not needed (as i disabled for android). so,i configured the "/libxml2/include/libxml/xmlversion.h" and  "/libxml2/src/config.h" accordingly ( just Disabled them)
example:

#if 0
#define LIBXML_ICONV_ENABLED
#endif

*Disable the thread one too

#if 0
#defineLIBXML_THREAD_ENABLED
#endif

Comment: LIBXML_ICONV_ENABLED is already disabled, but I'm getting undefined reference error related to libicuuc. LIBXML_THREAD_ENABLED was disabled also, but i need to enable it to fix "error: use of undeclared identifier 'xmlOnceInit' occured by compiling threads.c.

Comment: I have commented out "#define LIBXML_ICU_ENABLED" in xmlversion.h, it seems OK now.

Comment: @Oğuzhan Koşar Already added icu library but getting "error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_open_53'".

Comment: @JigarShekh 
This kind of error generally comes when we do wrong in `target_link_libraries()` , `add_library()`,etc. Have a recheck on these. However it is difficult to predict certain cause for this kind of error in NDK as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add xml2 and icuc libraries to Android project. icuc should be added because it is used by xml2 lib. I downloaded libicuc.so and xml2 source code.

Here I used Android.mk and Application.mk files in jni/ folder:

```
# Filename: Application.mk
APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a
```

---

```
# Filename: Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := icuuc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libicuuc.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/icu/icu4c/source/common
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# include $(CLEAR_VARS)
# LOCAL_MODULE := xml2
# LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libxml2.so
# LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/xml
# LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/xml/include
# include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := xml2
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/xml
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/xml/include/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  xml/SAX.c \
                    xml/entities.c \
                    xml/encoding.c \
                    xml/error.c \
                    xml/parserInternals.c \
                    xml/parser.c \
                    xml/tree.c \
                    xml/hash.c \
                    xml/list.c \
                    xml/xmlIO.c \
                    xml/xmlmemory.c \
                    xml/uri.c \
                    xml/valid.c \
                    xml/xlink.c \
                    xml/debugXML.c \
                    xml/xpath.c \
                    xml/xpointer.c \
                    xml/xinclude.c \
                    xml/nanohttp.c \
                    xml/nanoftp.c \
                    xml/DOCBparser.c \
                    xml/catalog.c \
                    xml/globals.c \
                    #xml/threads.c \
                    xml/c14n.c \
                    xml/xmlstring.c \
                    xml/xmlregexp.c \
                    xml/xmlschemas.c \
                    xml/xmlschemastypes.c \
                    xml/xmlunicode.c \
                    xml/xmlreader.c \
                    xml/relaxng.c \
                    xml/dict.c \
                    xml/SAX2.c \
                    xml/legacy.c \
                    xml/chvalid.c \
                    xml/pattern.c \
                    xml/xmlsave.c \
                    xml/xmlmodule.c \
                    xml/xmlwriter.c \
                    xml/schematron.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := icuuc
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

However, I'm getting clang++ linker error and so many undefined reference error as below. I couldn't find any soulution to fix this issue.

```
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\SatIP\jni>C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-bui
ld
Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-14.
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libicuuc.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libicuuc.so
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= SAX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= entities.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= encoding.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= error.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= parserInternals.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= parser.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= tree.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= hash.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= list.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= xmlIO.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= xmlmemory.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= uri.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= valid.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= xlink.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= debugXML.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= xpath.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= xpointer.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= xinclude.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= nanohttp.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= nanoftp.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= DOCBparser.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= catalog.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : xml2 <= globals.c
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libxml2.so
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:268: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrEqua
l'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:264: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrEqua
l'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:272: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrEqua
l'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:278: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrEqua
l'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:174: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDictLoo
kup'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:176: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDictLoo
kup'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:178: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDictLoo
kup'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:168: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrdup'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:170: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrdup'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:172: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrdup'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:181: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrlen'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:184: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDictLoo
kup'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:186: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrndup
'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:705: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrdup'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:597: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrstr'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:964: error: undefined reference to 'xmlStrchr'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:111: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDictOwn
s'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:114: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDictOwn
s'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:117: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDictOwn
s'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/entities.c:119: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDictOwn
s'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:113: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_open_
59'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:119: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_setTo
UCallBack_59'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:123: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_setFr
omUCallBack_59'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:130: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_open_
59'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:136: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_close
_59'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:139: error: undefined reference to 'UCNV_TO_U_
CALLBACK_STOP_59'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:139: error: undefined reference to 'UCNV_FROM_
U_CALLBACK_STOP_59'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:145: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_close
_59'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:146: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_close
_59'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:1884: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_conv
ertEx_59'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:2066: error: undefined reference to 'xmlBufUse
'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:2069: error: undefined reference to 'xmlBufAva
il'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:2086: error: undefined reference to 'xmlBufGro
w'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:2087: error: undefined reference to 'xmlBufAva
il'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:2095: error: undefined reference to 'xmlBufEnd
'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:2096: error: undefined reference to 'xmlBufCon
tent'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:2097: error: undefined reference to 'xmlBufShr
ink'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/encoding.c:2098: error: undefined reference to 'xmlBufAdd
Len'
...
...
...
...
undefined reference to 'xmlSaveForm
atFileTo'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:3109: error: undefined reference to 'xmlRMutexL
ock'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:3181: error: undefined reference to 'xmlRMutexU
nlock'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:3092: error: undefined reference to 'xmlNewRMut
ex'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:3205: error: undefined reference to 'xmlRMutexL
ock'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:3220: error: undefined reference to 'xmlRMutexU
nlock'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:3215: error: undefined reference to 'xmlRMutexU
nlock'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:3210: error: undefined reference to 'xmlRMutexU
nlock'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:3281: error: undefined reference to 'xmlRMutexL
ock'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:3295: error: undefined reference to 'xmlFreeRMu
tex'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:3418: error: undefined reference to 'xmlRMutexL
ock'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:2235: error: undefined reference to 'xmlIsPubid
Char_tab'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:2235: error: undefined reference to 'xmlIsPubid
Char_tab'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/catalog.c:1360: error: undefined reference to 'xmlGetThre
adId'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Intern
alSubset'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2IsStan
dalone'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2HasInt
ernalSubset'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2HasExt
ernalSubset'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Resolv
eEntity'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetEnt
ity'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Entity
Decl'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Notati
onDecl'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Attrib
uteDecl'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Elemen
tDecl'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Unpars
edEntityDecl'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2SetDoc
umentLocator'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2StartD
ocument'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2EndDoc
ument'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2StartE
lement'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2EndEle
ment'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Refere
nce'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Charac
ters'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Charac
ters'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Proces
singInstruction'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Commen
t'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetPar
ameterEntity'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2CDataB
lock'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Extern
alSubset'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXLocator: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetPub
licId'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXLocator: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetSys
temId'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXLocator: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetLin
eNumber'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:xmlDefaultSAXLocator: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetCol
umnNumber'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Inter
nalSubset'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2IsSta
ndalone'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2HasIn
ternalSubset'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2HasEx
ternalSubset'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Resol
veEntity'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Entit
yDecl'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2SetDo
cumentLocator'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Start
Document'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2EndDo
cument'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Start
Element'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2EndEl
ement'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Refer
ence'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Chara
cters'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Ignor
ableWhitespace'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2Comme
nt'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/xml2/xml/globals.o:C:/Users/user/An
droidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:docbDefaultSAXHandler: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetPa
rameterEntity'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:50: error: undefined reference to 'xmlNewMutex'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:61: error: undefined reference to 'xmlFreeMutex
'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:64: error: undefined reference to '__xmlGlobalI
nitMutexDestroy'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:50: error: undefined reference to 'xmlNewMutex'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:565: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetS
ystemId'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:565: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetC
olumnNumber'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:565: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetL
ineNumber'
C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/jni/xml/globals.c:565: error: undefined reference to 'xmlSAX2GetP
ublicId'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SatIP/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libxml2.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern. It might help as i am using CMake build-system with AndroidStudio2.0+ . However i have updated my answer down.